# MySQL: Multiple Queries with Same Connection Object

Tags: php, mysql

I have a registration script for one of my websites where I first check if the email entered by the user matches one that is in the database, and if it does, then return that there was a match found and do not insert their new account into the database.

**- I would like to know if there is a way to accomplish what I am doing with only one mysql connection object rather than initializing two of them?**

**- Also, I feel like my code is pretty messy and would love some extra opinions on how to write it better. Thanks!**

***Note:*** The validation boolean will be used in the future, so ignore the fact that it does nothing.

```
<?php
include '../portfolio/libraries/settings.php';

$first = $_POST['first'];
$middle = $_POST['middle'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$emailFound = false;
$validation = true;

if ($_POST['type'] == "Student") {
    $type = "0";
} else {
    $type = "1";
}

$connect = mysqli_connect($HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DATABASE);
$connect1 = mysqli_connect($HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DATABASE);

$result = $connect1->prepare("SELECT email FROM AUTH_User WHERE email = ?");
$result->bind_param("s", $email);
$result->execute();

while($result->fetch()) {
    $emailFound = true;
}

if (!$emailFound) {
    if ($middle != "" || $middle != null) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO AUTH_User (email, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, is_faculty) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $email, $first, $middle, $last, $type);

        if ($stmt->execute() && $validation) {
            echo "success";
        }
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO AUTH_User (email, FirstName, LastName, is_faculty) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $email, $first, $last, $type);

        if ($stmt->execute() && $validation) {
            echo "success";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "found";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use only one $connect :)

Maybe i can recommend you to use PDO to make query : http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

And I tried to clear your code with my own experience, so I haven't the better way to code ;)

```
include '../portfolio/libraries/settings.php';

$first = $_POST['first'];
$middle = $_POST['middle'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$email = $_POST['email'];  
$emailFound = false;
$validation = true;

$type = ($_POST['type'] == "Student")? 0 : 1 ;

$connect = mysqli_connect($HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DATABASE);

$result = $connect->prepare("SELECT email FROM AUTH_User WHERE email = ?");
$result->bind_param("s", $email);
$result->execute();

if(!$result->fetch()) {
    if (isset($middle)) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO AUTH_User (email, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, is_faculty) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $email, $first, $middle, $last, $type);

        if ($stmt->execute() && $validation)
            echo "success";

    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO AUTH_User (email, FirstName, LastName, is_faculty) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $email, $first, $last, $type);

        if ($stmt->execute() && $validation)
            echo "success";
    }
} else {
    echo "found";
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the code you supplied doesn't work with only one `$connect` statement. I added back `$connect1` and it worked. I forgot about this though: `$type = ($_POST['type'] == "Student")? 0 : 1 ;`, that will definitely knock some lines off. Same with the lack of while() loop.

Comment: You can check the example of the manual to use multiples queries  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php ;)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. One problem, the $result->num_rows always returns 0 in your code. I tried echo'ing out the number of rows inside my while loop and I kept getting 0. Any ideas?

Comment: I edit, you are in procedural style so use this : `mysqli_num_rows($result)`   (check my code to see) And maybe your querie never return result ^^

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in /var/www/html/dev/editButton/register.php on line 21`

Comment: My query does return a result because the original code works fine :P

Comment: I edited my answer with other way to use mysql_num_rows, and i add mysqli_free_result to use only one connect, you need to empty result set i think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57119/discussion-between-nicolas-and-kommu).